How to fix IntelliJ IDEA (Windows + WSL) always changing the selected keymap on WSL?
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 on Windows to work on WSL projects and the problem is that everytime I open a project the selected keymap defaults to Windows instead of my custom Eclipse copy.
The keymap is correctly kept on the Windows app but it seems to have no effect on the WSl side.

Indeed, on the WSL IDE I have to select the desired keymap everytime.

Can I hardcode the desired keymap ID in some configuration file?
Using this VM Option both on the Client (WSL) and Server (Windows) didn't fix it:
https://jetbrains.github.io/projector-client/mkdocs/latest/ij_user_guide/server_customization/#enable-auto-keymap-setting
-DORG_JETBRAINS_PROJECTOR_SERVER_AUTO_KEYMAP=false

Related issues:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-7944/Client-forgets-keymap-periodically
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-6598/Selected-keymap-randomly-switches-back-from-custom-keymap-to-the-Windows-default


Out team is already working on this issue. Please follow this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-7944/Client-forgets-keymap-periodically
